# Vs code live preview markdown

Tags: visual-studio-code, markdown

Is there a setting or plugin for vs code that would allow the simmilar functionality of markdown editing as [Typora](https://typora.io/)?

Comment: You can use built-in preview of the VSCode to see live output of Markdown file. But I couldn't find any solution (no extension) which allows you editing like Typora.